# Error for MultiSelect selection on .GetOpenFileName on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I've created a `Userform` on excel 2010 VBA (7.0) which will transfer a file selected by the user via the `.GetOpenFileName` property. The file paths of the selected files are then inserted into the `ListBox`

My issue is at the moment I am trying to use a `MultiSelect`,  however when I give `.GetOpenFileName` the `Multiselect` property to send the file paths to my `ListBox` (which is Multiline enabled) I am presented with a type mismatch error shown for the `GetOpenFileName` line of code. Code sample is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click ()
Dim strFilePath As String

StrFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename (,,,, MultiSelect:= True)
If strFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub

FilesFrom.Value = strFilePath

End Sub
```

FilesFrom being the listbox I want the filepaths to go into. I have the code working to allow the user to select a single file and transfer that but it won't allow me to populate this listbox with multiple filepaths.

Any ideas on how I can allow the user to select multiple files and insert the file paths into the listbox named FilesFrom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `MultiSelect` returns an `Array`.

The code below should be exactly what you want. It caters for Multi or Single Selection.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      'GetOpenFile MultiSelect will return an Array if more than one is selected
      Dim FilePathArray As Variant
      FilePathArray = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , MultiSelect:=True)

      If IsArray(FilePathArray) Then

           Dim ArraySize As Long
           ArraySize = UBound(FilePathArray, 1) - LBound(FilePathArray, 1) + 1

           Dim ArrayPosition As Long
           For ArrayPosition = 1 To ArraySize

                If Not FilePathArray(ArrayPosition) = Empty Then
                'Replace "UserForm1" with the name of your Userform
                UserForm1.FilesFrom.AddItem (FilePathArray(ArrayPosition))
                End If

           Next ArrayPosition

      ElseIf FilePathArray <> False Then

           'Replace "UserForm1" with the name of your Userform
           UserForm1.FilesFrom.AddItem (FilePathArray)

      End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Won't this error out if user selects cancel from the dialog?

Comment: That will error if the user clicks Cancel. You could use: `If IsArray(FilePathArray) Then`

Comment: @Rory, It has not bombed out on me when pressing Cancel or terminate on the MultiSelect Dialog box. But thanks anyway because i saw that bombed for a single selection, It works perfectly for me for Single and Multi selections or if you press cancel or terminate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. @Jean-Pierre, it worked perfectly thank you, marked yours as the correct answer. I knew it would be something to do with arrays but really don't know anything about storing/presenting them. Thanks again.

Comment: There will be no error but the statement below `ElseIf FilePathArray <> False Then` (`False<>False`) will never be executed i.e. it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Application.GetOpenFilename seems a bit limited to me. I typically use a variation on the following snippet. It copies all selected filenames into astrFiles() which you can then process as required.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim astrFiles() As String

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varSelectedItem as Variant
    Dim objFileSelect As FileDialog
    Set objFileSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    objFileSelect.AllowMultiSelect = True
    ' Skip if user clicks cancel on dialogue
    If objFileSelect.Show = True Then
        ' Copy from Variant() to String()
        ReDim astrFiles(objFileSelect.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
        For Each varSelectedItem In objFileSelect.SelectedItems
            astrFiles(i) = varSelectedItem
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If

    Set objFileSelect = Nothing
End Function
```

You could then load the results into a TextBox or the like with the following:

```
FilesFrom.Value = Join(astrFiles,vbCr)
```

Answer (score 0):

### GetOpenFilename - MultiSelect

**Use a Variant Variable**

- When using [`GetOpenFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) with `MultiSelect` set to `True`, the result is either the boolean `False` (when the dialog was canceled) or a **1D one-based array** containing the path(s) of the selected file(s).
- Using your code that uses a string type variable, there will be no error if you cancel the dialog because the resulting boolean (`False`) will get converted to the string `False`. A similar conversion is not possible with an array even if it has only one element, hence the type mismatch error.

**In the User Form's Code Module**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim FilePaths As Variant
    FilePaths = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , True)
    
    If VarType(FilePaths) = vbBoolean Then
        'FilesFrom.Clear
        'MsgBox "No file selected!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    FilesFrom.List = FilePaths

End Sub
```